# Who is this anime character with animal ears?

Tags: character-identification, merchandise

A friend got me this keychain thinking it was a different character. I think it's cute but I would like to know who it is. [image: pink hair, brown fox(?) ears, brown tail and what kinda looks like baals outfit from genshin impact]

Comment: [Tamamo-no-Mae](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Tamamo-no-Mae)

Comment: What does this have to do with science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: @user14111 - Because women don't usually have fox ears.

Answer (score 6):

This is [Tamamo-no-Mae](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Tamamo-no-Mae) from the multi-media series [Fate](https://typemoon.fandom.com/wiki/Fate_series).

[image]

In this instance, your keychain is one manufactured by *[Huizhou Huaqiu Acrylic Products](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Top-ranking-products-Boku-No-Keyring_1600126410934.html)*. It appears to be out of stock at present.

[image]

Comment: hat-tip to Turamarth for the assist.